# SWIFT trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, swift

I don't see any reference to standard trig functions (Sine, Cosine, Tangent) in the SWIFT language reference.  What is the recommended way to add them?  Are there libraries that should be loaded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can still use them as global functions as defined in the Darwin module (imported automatically with Foundation)

```
import Darwin
var num = CDouble(10)
sin(num)
```